# Combine multiple rows using SUM that share a same column value but has different other column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I thought this would be a very simple query but for some reason, I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for. I have a table that has this structure. I just want a single entry for each account while summing the charges. I don't really care which date I keep, just one of them.

```
Account Charges Charges2    Date
1       100      50       1/1/2015
1       50       0        1/2/2015
2       50       0        2/4/2015
2       70       30       2/19/2015
3       100      0        1/12/2014
4       0        20       4/3/2015
4       40       20       4/9/2015
```

The result I want is:

```
Account Charges Charges2    Date
1       150      50       1/1/2015
2       120      30       2/4/2015
3       100      0        1/12/2014
4       40       40       4/3/2015
```

The result I currently get is:

```
Account Charges Charges2    Date
1       100      50       1/1/2015
2       70       30       2/19/2015
3       100      0        1/12/2014
4       40       40       4/9/2015
```

I thought this would be very simple and I tried below. But this doesn't sum them up, it just seems to return the rows where Charges2 is NOT 0.

```
SELECT Account, SUM(Charges) As TotCharges, SUM(Charges2) AS TotCharges2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Account
ORDER BY Account
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you display the results of your current query?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60. 

The current results I get are
Account     Charges    Charges2    Date
1                100           50                1/1/2015
2                70             30                2/19/2015
3                100           0                  1/12/2014
4                40             20                4/9/2015

Comment: Please put those results in your original post by editing it.  Thanks.  It will always look ugly inside comments.

Comment: You wouldn't get a row for account 3 if it were only showing those with `charges2 > 0`. There's something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `min()` aggregate function to the date to limit the number of rows returned to one per account:

```
SELECT 
  Account, 
  SUM(Charges)  AS TotCharges, 
  SUM(Charges2) AS TotCharges2, 
  MIN(Date) AS Date
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Account
ORDER BY Account
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1bac3/4)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. I don't even need the date field at the moment so I tried removing it from the SELECT statement. It still returns the same result.